# Trying to use symbolic link gives me "command not found" error

Tags: symbolic-link

I created a symbolic link via `ln -s pathname/folder/file.py whatever` and I now have a bright blue link in my home directory with the symbolic link command name but when I try `whatever hello_world`, it's giving me an error saying `whatever: command not found`.

What I want to do works when I re-type out the pathname and file but the symbolic link seems to be doing nothing....which means I did something wrong

Comment: Have you tried `python whatever hello_world`?

Answer (score 4):

That is likely nothing to do with symbolic links *per se* - it is probably because by default the shell does not search the current directory for executable files (regardless of whether they are regular files or symbolic links) - if you add the relative path to `whatever` i.e.

```
./whatever
```

it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that the path which contains the sym link is in PATH enviroment variable

```
echo $PATH
```

or use ./whatever

to add the path to your $PATH
edit .bashrc (It will specific for the current user if you want to be for all users edit /etc/profile) and add:

```
PATH=$PATH:pathname/folder/
export $PATH
```

then save and exit and run

```
source .bashrc
```